# How do I make the stopwatch start automatically on page load? without using the start button

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make the stopwatch start automatically on page load? without using the start button. This stopwatch will start only by by pressing the start button, but I want the the stopwatch start on page load.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  stopWatch();
}

function stopWatch() {
  let time, intervalId;
  let startBtn = document.getElementById("startBtn");
  let stopBtn = document.getElementById("stopBtn");

  startBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    time = -1;
    incrementTime();
    intervalId = setInterval(incrementTime, 1000);
    startBtn.disabled = true;
    stopBtn.disabled = false;
  });

  stopBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    startBtn.disabled = false;
    stopBtn.disabled = true;
  });

  function incrementTime() {
    time++;
    document.getElementById("time").textContent =
      ("0" + Math.trunc(time / 60)).slice(-2) +
      ":" + ("0" + (time % 60)).slice(-2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="time" style="border: 3px solid blue; text-align: center;font-size: 2em; margin-bottom: 10px">00:00</div>
<button id="startBtn">Start the clock</button>
<button id="stopBtn" disabled="true">Stop the clock</button>
```

Comment: why not load it on the body? <body onload="stopWatch()">

Comment: @jae.phoenix That is a horrible idea. Don't use inline event handlers ESPECIALLY not in the body tag. Anyway that will not click the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the buttons - not hidden them

If you want the clock without buttons, do not have buttons

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const clock = document.getElementById("time");
  let time = -1, intervalId;
  function incrementTime() {
    time++;
    clock.textContent =
      ("0" + Math.trunc(time / 60)).slice(-2) +
      ":" + ("0" + (time % 60)).slice(-2);
  }
  incrementTime();
  intervalId = setInterval(incrementTime, 1000);
});
```

```html
<div id="time" style="border: 3px solid blue; text-align: center;font-size: 2em; margin-bottom: 10px">00:00</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code | you can also just hide the start button

```
window.onload = function() {
  stopWatch();
  document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
}
```

if you dont want button :

```
function stopWatch() {
  let time, intervalId;
  let stopBtn = document.getElementById("stopBtn");

   function strtWatch() {
    time = -1;
    incrementTime();
    intervalId = setInterval(incrementTime, 1000);        
    stopBtn.disabled = false;
  }
 strtWatch();

  stopBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);        
    stopBtn.disabled = true;
  });

  function incrementTime() {
    time++;
    document.getElementById("time").textContent =
      ("0" + Math.trunc(time / 60)).slice(-2) +
      ":" + ("0" + (time % 60)).slice(-2);
  }
}
```

Comment: no  in your answer it can not access startBtn variable cuz its in declared inside the stop watch function.

Comment: See my update. It already worked but now it is more logical

Comment: But how to start the timer and remove both start and stop button?

Comment: @RafIzan using  document.getElementById("myBtn").click(); you can start the timer on page load automatically

Comment: @HammadAhmedkhan Yes, but how to start without even using button? I mean I want completely remove the button.

Comment: @HammadAhmedkhan Thank you very much, this is exactly I want. :D